# Given two fair dice, what is the expected value of their product?

Tags: probability, expected-value, independence, dice

> Question: Given two fair dice, what is the expected value of their product?

My attempt:

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be scores by first and second die respectively. 
Note that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. 
Then 
$$E(X_1X_2) = E(X_1)E(X_2) = 3.5^2 = 12.25.$$

Is my calculation correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct.  As a general note, a thing like this could easily be checked by enumerating the $36$ cases.  But your method works fine here.

Answer (score 2):

The expectation of a product of independent random variables is equal to the product of their expectations.

$$E[X_1 X_2] = \sum_{x_1} \sum_{x_2} x_1 x_2 p(X_1 = x_1 {\rm \ and\ } X_2=x_2)$$
By independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$, 
$$p(X_1 = x_1 {\rm \ and\ } X_2=x_2) = p(X1=x1) p(X_2=x2)$$
so
$$E[X_1 X_2] = \sum_{x_1} \sum_{x_2} x_1 x_2 p(X_1 = x_1) p(X_2=x_2) \\
= \sum_{x_1} x_1 p_1(X_1 = x_1) \cdot \sum_{x_2} x_2 p(X2=x2) \\
\sum_{x_1} x_1 p(x_1) E[X_2] \\
E[X_1]E[X_2]$$

So you are correct with your calculations as long as the rolls are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach and answer are both correct. You could also take the average of the products of all possible cases.
$${\bar x}=\frac {{\sum_{i=1}^6}{\sum_{j=1}^6}ij}{6\times 6}$$
$${\bar x}=\biggr(\frac {6\times7}{2}\biggr)^2\times \frac {1}{36}$$
$${\bar x}=12.25$$